# Mixed variable, joint distribution, How do we know which one is continuous distribution, which one is discrete

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes, notation, mathematical-statistics

If we have one continuous r.v. $x$ and a discrete r.v. $y$ which takes one of the two values $y_1$ and $y_2$. Let's say we know the prior probabilities $P(y_1)$ and $P(y_2)$.

From Bayes theorem we know

$p(y_i,x) = P(y_i|x)\cdot p(x)$

$P$ corresponds to prob. mass function, $p$ corresponds to prob. density function.

On LHS we have a probability value coming from a continuous distribution. On RHS we have product of two probabilities one coming from a discrete distribution, another coming from a continuous distribution.

My question is - Why is first term on RHS $P(y_i|x)$ and not $p(y_i|x)$ (Since it's possible that, given $x$, the probability that $y$ will take a value of $y_i$, might smoothly vary from $0$ to $1$)? Are there different ways of writing Bayes theorem that will have $p(y_i|x)$ instead of $P(y_i|x)$?

Comment: I think you're confused. The values that $y_i$ can take don't change from when you condition on $x$ to when you don't. If $y$ is a discrete r.v., it remains discrete. The *probabilities* it takes those discrete values can change as $x$ changes and that can happen in a smooth way.

Comment: @Glen_b forget what values $y_i$ can take, think of what values $P(y_i|x)$ can take. It's not discrete set of probabilities. If we plot $P(y_i|x)$ and it might look continuous. edit. i think i got what u r saying.

Comment: $P(y_i|x)$ considered as a function of $x$ varies continuously with $x$, but $P$ is the pmf for $y$, and as such is defined over the discrete values $y$ takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Since it's possible that, given x, the probability that y will take a value of yi, might smoothly vary from 0 to 1)

I believe you are misunderstanding what the distinction between a pdf and a pmf is based on. A pdf corresponds to the case when the *argument* of the probability function (for lack of a better alternative term) takes values on a continuum. Similarly, a pmf corresponds to the case when the *argument* of the probability function takes discrete values.

The argument of the probability function of $y|x$ is $y$, not $x$. You should think of $x$ as a constant (arbitrary, but fixed) in the probability function of $y|x$. Since $y$, the argument is discrete, the probability function of $y|x$ is a pmf, and indeed the notation $P(y_i|x)$ is correct.

Note: All my comments are based on the assumption that pdfs/pmfs exist when they need to. I am not talking about pathological cases here.

Comment: consider this view - a pmf has only a discrete set of values ALLOWED for probability, whereas pdf has infinite number of values allowed for probability. If we consider this, then P(y|x) is capable of taking infinite values and not discrete values.

Comment: i have understood it based on glen's comment. your way of explaining was a bit convoluted for me. anyway upvoted for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to understand this is to plot $P(y_i|x)$ Vs $y_i$. It's discrete distribution because X axis can only take discrete values. Thanks to @Glen_b for comment.

Comment: I think a better way to see the difference is actually to plot it in terms of both $y$ and $x$. You'll see a pair of side-by-side smooth densities. If you fix $y=y_i$ it's a continuous function in $x$ (but not a density in general). If you fix $x$ - which is what the conditioning symbol says to do - then it's a slice across those curves - a pair of delta functions, describing the probability that $y=y_i$.

Comment: @Glen_b can we write $p(y_i,x)$ as a function of $p(y_i|x)$ and $p(x)$ instead of $P(y_i|x)$ and $p(x)$? Can we write any equation that uses $p(y_i|x)$ in some form or is it a useless concept?

Comment: $y$ is *discrete*. A probability function for $y$ - no matter what it conditions on - will be a pmf. I am baffled by your difficulty with that point.

Comment: @Glen_b I know $y$ is discrete. By $p(y|x)$ i mean when X axis is $x$ instead of $y$. Is this a non-standard concept $p_x(y|x)$?

Comment: @Glen_b consider a plot of $p_x(y|x)$ instead of $P_y(y|x)$. Is the first way of notation non-standard? If not, can it be used in any way in bayes equation?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. $P(y|x)$ says 'fix $x$, and $P$ tells you the probability that $y=y_i$, for $i=1,2$'. If you consider it as a function of $x$ - i.e. $L_1(x) = P(y=y_1|x)$, then it's not a density. It's a likelihood.

Comment: @Glen_b subscript of $p$ or $P$ determines what the X axis will be, am i right? $P$ cannot have $x$ as subscript, and $p$ cannot have $y$ as subscript as $p$ is notation for PDF.

Comment: @Glen_b sorry about that, got a bit excited with discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15489/discussion-between-user13107-and-glen-b).